# How do I optimize size of my unity word puzzle game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We have developed [**Word Puzzle Game for android**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wrapapp.wordgame). The size is greater than 20 MB because we have developed game with the help of Unity game engine.

Even blank project will take approx 10 MB for APK in Unity.
Your advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the documentation Manual on [Reducing the file size of your build](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html). Also this [forum post](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1033002/view.html) could help you. Otherwise a simple Google search will give you many results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this ?
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html
I'm afraid you won't find more.

There will always be a minimal size, even for an empty project, because you're embedding mono, unity engine, etc...

If you want total control, the question you should ask yourself is :

"Do I really need Unity for a word puzzle ?"

If your game is made mostly with scripts, you could maybe convert it to a native app ?

Comment: FLX, it was helpful.
I think native app idea is good here. Have to hire freelancer for native app development.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, good for him/her ! However, is 20mb THAT terrible that you want to throw your current work ? I just looked my phone, and for example, a stupid torch lamp app is taking >35MB. So 20MB, for a full game, doesn't sound so extreme to me !